# primefaces red box validation from managedbean

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a form which is validated in server side. From primefaces commandbutton action I call to the managed bean that does all the work and validates the form. The managed bean validation throws some FacesMessage errors as needed but... I want red borders on the boxes with errors and I dont know how to do this from the managed bean.

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "summary", "detail"))`

Comment: you need to use css to do this, apply a class on the element having the errors and then style it as you wish

Comment: What code are you currently working with? Post your view code here

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by calling setValid(false) on the component:

```
((UIInput) component).setValid(false);
```

If you don't have a reference to the UIInput component, you can get it as follows:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("id");
```